# Rails 3 POST Redirect GET - empty GET response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Rails 3.0.9, I'm trying to redirect after a post to the ***create*** method in ***UserController***, Firebug shows the POST is sent correctly, my create method is executed, POST returns '302' moved temporarily. As expected the, GET request routes to the **new** action of the *UserProfileController*, **HOWEVER**, there is not response to the GET request!

I tried this with other controllers/actions also with the same result.  Why is the GET request after redirect empty?  What am I doing wrong?  A standard request to /users/profile/new does return the expected GET response.

```
UserController

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user]) if params[:user]
  logger.debug (params[:user])
  logger.debug @user
  logger.debug @user.valid?
  logger.debug @user.errors

  if(@user.valid?)
    session[:new_user] = @user

    logger.debug "Creating User Profile"
  end

  redirect_to new_user_profile_url  # controller => user_profile, action => new
end

UserProfileController

def new
  @user_profile = UserProfile.new

  # check to see if the new user is in session, if not, then redirect to previous page
  user = session[:new_user]

  logger.debug 'going to right url???'
  logger.debug request.method
  logger.debug request.format
  logger.debug request.headers
  logger.debug request.url

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml { render :xml => @user_profile }
  end
end
```

Server Log

```
Creating User Profile
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/profile/new
Completed 302 Found in 325ms


Started GET "/users/profile/new" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Aug 05 10:38:38 -0500 2011
  Processing by UserProfileController#new as HTML
going to right url???
GET
text/html
http://localhost:3000/users/profile/new
Rendered shared/_trust_reports.haml (45.0ms)
Rendered user_profile/new.haml within layouts/application (590.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 973ms (Views: 616.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Have you started the app with `rails server` or this happen in production with other server? What about your logging messages, are they logged in server log? Is there anything else in the server log?

Comment: I'm running in dev mode w/ rails server, update w/ log additions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was my own mistake, I did not realize the javascript/theme we were using defaulted to submit all forms via ajax.  After changing the default behavior, it worked as expected, thanks for the suggestion Fabio.

Answer (score 0):

According to that log file the server has ended its job and has rendered the output. It could be a problem with your browser (sometimes firebug and other developer tools lock the browser) or it could be a problem with the webserver. I'm assuming you're using webrick (the default one).

Please try your code with another browser and if the problem remains try with a different rails server, there are a lot of them: passenger, unicorn, mongrel, thin.

Usually I develop with passenger standalone, you could install it with `gem install passenger` and then from your rails root simply run

```
passenger start
```

The first time it will take some minutes because it will download nginx standalone and it will compile it.